# TypeGraphql InputType Field with enum value doesn't let in string (quoted text)

Tags: typescript, typegraphql

Created a project with TypeGraphql in typescript. Trying to make a field to be an enum with string values. If I send these values , or names to the mutation endpoint they throw me an error:

```
"errors": [
        {
            "message": "Expected type Tipe!, found \"Contract\"; Did you mean the enum value Contract?",
            "locations": [
                {
```

Following DTO:

```
import { Tipe } from "../validators/enums/ContactEnums";

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Contact extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column("enum", { enum: Tipe })
  tipe: Tipe;
```

Enum type:

```
export enum Tipe {
    "Contract" = "CONTRACT",
    "Person" = "PERSON"
}
```

Inputtype:

```
@InputType()
export class ContactInput {
  @Field()
  id: string;

  @Field(() => Tipe)
  tipe: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use variables if you want to send enum values as strings:

```
query SampleQuery($sampleArg: Tipe!) {
  sample(sampleArg: $sampleArg) {
    field 
  }
}
```

```
{
  sampleArg: "Contract"
}
```

If you make your query static and provide the enum inline, you can't wrap it in quotes:

```
query {
  sample(sampleArg: Contract) {
    field 
  }
}
```